# Notifications vanish when answer is converted to comment

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I noticed a "bug" (or maybe a conceptual shortcoming, but an important one) with converting answers to comments today.

Steps to reproduce:

1. User A answers a question.
2. User B comments on the answer with a reply. User A does not see the notification for the comment yet.
3. A moderator converts the answer *and* the comment to comments on the question (or elsewhere).

Now the notification for User A will vanish, so he won't know that he actually got a response before their answer was converted (nor will he know *that* their answer was converted unless they check). I can't see why this would be the intended behaviour, hence the bug tag.

My suggested fix is, when converting answers and comments to comments, to prepend `@UserA` to all comments that don't have a @ping already.

(There *would* be a notification if the comment had already contained `@UserA`, but that is likely not the case unless a larger number of comments accumulates before the answer gets converted.)